# unpack JSONB object with best performance

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

**There are a simple expression or function to "unpack" sub-objects, exploding it into the main object?**

---

Explaining with example:

```
SELECT '{"x":null,"A":{"foo":true,"bar":123},"B":2332}'::jsonb;  
-- = JSONB object with "A" as sub-object.
```

Is a typical case: I need "A" content into the main object. And need that datatypes (number/boolean/null) are preserved, no "convert string solution" is valid. Also good perfomance is expected.

Remove "A" is ok with `- 'A'`, but, put back its contents , is not easy:

```
SELECT ('{"x":null,"A":{"foo":true,"bar":123},"B":2332}'::jsonb - 'A')
    || '{"foo":true,"bar":123}'::jsonb; -- aim result, unpacked!

SELECT ('{"x":null,"A":{"foo":true,"bar":123},"B":2332}'::jsonb - 'A')
    || ('{"A":{"foo":true,"bar":123}}'::jsonb)->'A' -- NOT WORKS...
```

**How to put back "A" contents?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator `||` has higher priority than operator `->`, so you need to move the parentheses around. I only changed the last from `::jsonb)->'A'` to `::jsonb->'A')` and it works:

```
SELECT 
    ('{"x":null,"A":{"foo":true,"bar":123},"B":2332}'::jsonb - 'A')
    || ('{"A":{"foo":true,"bar":123}}'::jsonb->'A');
```

Comment: Thanks (!). About PostgreSQL (v9.5) decision I think they are wrong, higher [precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) most be for `->` that is like an object-oriented path operator, always higher than algebric ones.

Comment: Well, technically they have same priority (they both fall into the category of [any other](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE), because they are not standard operators), so they are evaluated from left to right.